# Package for MRP

Tags: r

I have some survey data which I have to analyze. The data contains ~3000 cases. I want to calculate a regression for a small subsample of that data which is actually very small (just ~30 cases), so the standard errors get quite large. I want to use MRP (multilevel regression and poststratification) to analyze those cases. Is there a package in R for calculating an MRP?

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/alexdulin/MCmrp/man/mrp_model.html ?

Comment: I tried this already  `devtools::install_github("alexdulin/MCmrp")`.  I get the message: `ERROR: failed to lock directory`: If try this command `devtools::install_github("alexdulin/MCmrp", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock') `I get `staged installation is only possible with locking`

Comment: I addition this works only for a logistic regression but not for a linear one.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a package per se that I have found, but [this primer](https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/jkastellec/files/mrp_primer.pdf) gives a straightforward approach and I've found it useful.